# Python regex not matching for "," or end of string

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a single regular expression in python for below lines to grep the corresponding values:

```
establishmentCause mo-Signalling,
Freq = 6300
Radio Bearer ID = 0, Physical Cell ID = 396
```

Here i want to fetch the values for each header, I am using the below regular expression to fetch values and it succeeds for all except "Radio Bearer ID"

```
pat = re.compile(r'%s\s[=\s]*\b(.*)\b(?:,|\Z)'%items[i])
value = pat.search(line)
print(value.group(1))
```

This gives the output for `"Radio Bearer ID"` as `0, Physical Cell ID = 396` where as I want only `0`. Can some one please tell me what the problem is with my regular expression even though I am matching `,` and `\Z` the re engine dose not limit the match till `,` but continues further.

Comment: What is `items[i]`? Please post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What are you trying to extract for the `establishmentCause` line?  Can you show us the output you expect from each line?

Comment: @RedX : items[i] is a list using which I am running a loop to grep values. In the above example it will have values like "establishmentCause,Freq,Radio Bearer ID,Physical Cell ID"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to create a dictionary from the above lines with key being "establishmentCause" and its corresponding value being "mo-Signalling" and so on for Freq, Physical Cell ID etc

Comment: I am not sure why you have to use compile here. As far as i know, compile is typically used when you kind of have to retype the same pattern over and over again. You might just use re.search instead. I know it is not what it is about but still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantifier `*` is greedy. You can use the non-greedy version `*?` to match as little as possible before the `,` or end of string (`\Z`):

```
pat = re.compile(r'%s\s[=\s]*\b(.*?)\b(?:,|\Z)'%items[i])
```

Alternatively, you can use a character class excluding `,` instead:

```
pat = re.compile(r'%s\s[=\s]*\b([^,]*)\b(?:,|\Z)'%items[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lookbehind & Lookahead

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """establishmentCause mo-Signalling,
Freq = 6300
Radio Bearer ID = 0, Physical Cell ID = 396"""

pat = re.compile(r'(?<=Radio Bearer ID = )(.*)(?=,)')
value = pat.search(s)
print(value.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
0
```